# Function App outbound public IPs altough VNet injection enabled

Tags: azure-functions

I've configured VNet injection for my Function App and have set the `Route All` optio to `Enabled`. However, what I don't understand why there's a bunch of public IP addresses displayed in `Outbound addresses`. Looking at MS documentation, enabling VNet injection brings the service inside the VNet forcing all traffic to the VNet. What am I missing ?

[Func App VNet integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Ix2.png)
[Route all enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSypI.png)

Comment: You route all the trafifc to the VNET but for outbound connection (internet) unless you have a NAT Gateway attached, the function app will use these outbound IPs.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. So if I place a NSG on the integration subnet, will this internet outbound connection be subject of this NSG rules? From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/network-secure-outbound-traffic-azure-firewall#prerequisites `Verify that Route All is enabled. This setting is enabled by default, which tells App Service to route all outbound traffic through the integrated virtual network. If you disable it, only traffic to private IP addresses will be routed through the virtual network.` This seams to be the case?

Comment: What is the issue with the outbound addresses you are seeing ? If you are trying to get a dedicated IP, you probably need a NAT gateway: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway/nat-overview. I guess it s really depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Vnet integration with azure function is a feature to use azure functions to connect to resources in an azure virtual network. vnet integration is only for making outbound calls from your app into your vnet. Say I have a private endpoint enable Storage Account with public access disabled. How would it reach that Storage Account without VNet integration ? In fact I have also enabled diag settings on the Storage Account and can see calls being made to it from the Func App with an private IP address from the subnet range where it got injected. Hence not sure what is the use case for the pub IPs.

Comment: The public outbound ips are only for internet inbounds really in your case: Let say you need to call an external service and it requires IP whitelisting, you would need to give them the oubound public ips of the function app.

Comment: Thanks Thomsa ! So if I want to make my Function App entirely private, meaning it supposed to operate say withing a subscription and its resources, I could then a) not include any external dependencies to be called from within the code, b) perhaps to lock id down even more further, apply nsg to the integration subnet, or even route table that would deny Internet connectivity? Am I correct?

Comment: what sthe rational behind that ? Is this function only called from within the subnet ? You could always enable private endpoint on the function app as well soi it is completely private

Comment: yes, but the private endpoint, wouldn't it be only for inbound? the function would probably be triggered on a scheduled based (no HTTP trigger) but since the function will deal with highly sensitive data I would like it to be completely locked down, e.g. no outbound connectivity or whatsoever. That's why the VNet injection as well, to have the Storage Account that's used as backend for the function is also private endpoint enabled.

Comment: To visualize it, for AKS what we did, by default if you create an AKS private cluster, it would still use a public IP for all egress traffic. For us this was a big concern, because with this we would lose visibility, say an app got compromised and is exfiltrating data. So we had it locked down by configuring UDR outbound type to force all egress traffic trough our subscription where the Palo Alto FW's sit, to get visibility. I'm looking for a way to achieve the same with Function in Azure and I believe this is what VNet injecton would allow me to do.

Comment: Yeah so you're right, if the subnet integrated to your funtion app have a NSG rule to deny internet outbound traffic you should be ok.

Comment: Yep, but then I'm still not understanding why the public IPs. Once injected into a VNet the traffic should be subject to UDRs to route it in a way to go out to the internet (if needed).  Unfortunate the docs are not to great at explaining this. I might consider opening  a case with MS support for this.